# How to write an optimized code when you have a range of values in a LUT and the values are determined during run-time in C

Tags: c, optimization

I need to implement a LUT which looks like the following:

```
|   Range            | Value   |
|--------------------|---------|
| var < val1         | Invalid |
| -------------------| --------|
| val1 < var <= val2 | M = 0   |
|--------------------|---------|
| val2 < var <= val3 | M = 2   |
|--------------------|---------|
| val3 < var <= val4 | M = 4   |
|--------------------|---------|
```

val1, val2, val3 and val4 are configured during run-time and the value of var gets configured at a later point of time in another thread and that is when I need to compute the value of M. Also, if val1 = val2 (or if two values in any row are same) then that row becomes invalid (M can't have that value). val4 can be at the max 25. My question is, how do I implement this in an optimistic way? To make the code work I wrote a classic if..elseif..elseif statement but I know that there is a much more optimistic way to write it.
I tried computing an array of 25 elements when val1, val2 etc. get configured and loading the array after var gets configured (indexing based on var) but somehow after profiling, the performance seems to have become worse. Can anyone help me with a more optimized way to write it?

Comment: With `if/else if/else`. *but I know that there is a much more optimistic way to write it* - how do you know it? (BTW, optimistic is not the same as optimal)

Comment: Wildly guessing, but food for thought: If the values of `var` are not randomly distributed, but mostly fall into a specific range resulting in the same value of M that can be determined easily, the if-else construction might be faster than a lookup.

Comment: The table doesn't specify the outcome for `var == val1`. I suggest that the first row range be `var <= val1` to be consistent with the other rows. Doing that also makes the `if/else if/else` solution easier to implement. And unless you have more than four ranges, `if/else if/else` is the way to go.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with the two versions and the profiling code? Did you compile and test with the optimizations on?

Answer (score 0):

LUTs are good in benchmarks but not always so great in practice because of possible *cache misses* in big applications full of LUTs. An if-then-else statement can be very fast if the branch taken is often the same due to *branch prediction*. Alternatively to these two methods, you can use a *branch-less* code. Such approach is good when the input data are can hardly be predicted and when the conditions is not too costly. In your case you can use the following expression:

```c
/* This branch should almost always be taken and so 
   it should be well predicted by the processor */
if(var > val1) 
{
    /* Branch-less evaluation */
    M = (var > val2) + (var > val3);
    M = M + M;
}
else
{
    /* Error management */
}
```

This should just few cycles on modern (superscalar) processors. It may not always faster than a simple LUT regarding the target architecture and the workload.

If the `val1`, `val2` and `val3` values are very rarely updated, you can fill the LUT at update time (slow) and then use it.